# Our Blog: shouldn't it reflect our status as experts & also be easy to find and read?

Tags: discussion, blog

I just wanted to ask - **are there going to be a list of standards for our blog?** I'm assuming that we're putting ourselves out there as experts and so we want to maintain professionalism (while still being personal) in our writing.

**Also should there be standards around blog titles & meta information** for the purpose of SEO and for usability - so that users can identify content they want to read? Entries with ambiguous titles might get ignored when users are scanning, and won't display in searches (or if they do, they'll get ignored again).

**Eg. say you write a blog entry specifically about the impact of white space and how it should be used.**

**1st title example: 'Implications of lots of stuff on your page'**

It might be a fun title and seem personal and inviting, but if users are scanning for 'white space', 'usability', 'clutter', etc, all key words that relate to what they might be looking for content regarding, they're going to scan over this title.

It doesn't appropriately summarise your content.

It also wont come up in google searches for 'white space'.

**A better title would be: 'The impact of white space on page or application usability'**

This title summarises your post, has keywords that improve the ability of users to find things and will also show up in content searches.

Answer (score 3):

## How to get a community to write a blog

```
1 Get someone to write the first post.
2 Get someone to write the second post.
3 Get someone to write the third post.
4 ...
27 Worry about standards and professionalism.
```

;-)

Comment: ahahah :P ok good point